# How to match the chars of a string to the index of an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, char

I have a string that consists of numbers, that I want to match to the contents of an array of words.

Each char in the input string is matched to the position in the words array.

If I print out the values of `i` and `j` before the `if` statement, they are correct, `0 and 0`, `3 and 3`, etc. The loop below however never enters the `if` statement. Please help me understand why.

```
String input = "0356";
String[] words = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
String[] result = new String[4];

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        if (Character.toString(input.charAt(i)) == Integer.toString(j)) {
            result[i] = words[j];
        }   
    }
}
```

The result I am looking for:

```
result[] = {"zero","three","five","six"}
```

Comment: String comparison should always use `equals()`

Comment: `Character.toString(input.charAt(i)).equals(Integer.toString(j))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When compare String,you need to use `equals()` instead of `==`

So change

```
if (Character.toString(input.charAt(i)) == Integer.toString(j))
```

to

```
if (Character.toString(input.charAt(i)).equals(Integer.toString(j)))
```

Comment: Just one thing that Integer.toString() will always create String instance as it calls new internally, so for example if input string length is 20, 20*10 = 200 instance of String will be created by this solution. Anyways, +1 for the solution what OP asked for.

Comment: @AmanChhabra What would you suggest instead of Integer.toString, to avoid all the new instances of String being created?

Comment: @DevStep As in the above case, two instance of new String will be invoked , one by Character.toString and Integer.toString, I would suggest to go with comparison of Integer as suggested in my answer below : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51569979/1262248

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert it into integer, instead of playing with String.

```
 if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i))) == j)
```

Output:

```
jshell>     for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
   ...>         for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
   ...>             if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i))) == j)
   ...>    {
   ...>                 result[i] = words[j];
   ...>             }   
   ...>         }
   ...>     }

jshell> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
[zero, three, five, six]
```

> PS: One thing that you need to take care is that parseInt throws
>   NumberFormatException, so either ensure that your input string always
>   has numbers (may be you can validate it through regex) or handle the
>   exception properly

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with Java 8 streams could be:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class numberToWords {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "0356";
        String[] words = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

        String[] result = Arrays.stream( // Convert to stream
                input.split("")) // split each number
                .map(e -> words[Integer.valueOf(e)]) // map each number to the corresponding word index
                .toArray(String[]::new); // return the resulting array

        for (String string : result) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
zero
three
five
six
```